# Deleting files using PHP's ftp_delete function not working

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to delete files off my ftp server using php's ftp_delete function, however i can not seem to get it to work.

I have followed the instructions on the php man page [ftp_delete](https://www.php.net/function.ftp-delete) but still have had no luck.

Maybe i have missed something?

When using the file on my local testing server it would appear it connects fine, however when i upload the file to the remote server, i cannot connect at all.

**My Code**

```
<?php

// server credentials
$ftp_server = "address.myftpupload.com";
$ftp_username = "Password";
$ftp_userpass = "UserName";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login with username and password
ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

//change dir
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images");

// try to delete $file
$file = "webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images/metal_textures_silver.jpg";
if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {
echo "$file deleted successful\n";
} else {
echo "could not delete $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);


?>
```

Any help would be great, or even just a point in the right direction.

Comment: Do you get the `could not delete $file` message? Also are you sure the login is successful?

Comment: `if` on all FTP functions in my opinion.

Comment: When on my local server yes i recieve a message saying either yes it workes or no it didnt, but when i upload it to my remote server i just get the could not could not connect error?! I find that weird.

Comment: @ohgodwhy could you elaborate on you comment?

Comment: Ohgodwhy means you should do error check on every FTP function.  Something like `$res = ftp_login(...); if (!res) echo("error on login...");`.

Comment: or use `or die('blablabla');` on each of them ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual problem was that because the file was on the FTP server already it didn't need all the login and credentials

```
// server credentials
$ftp_server = "address.myftpupload.com";
$ftp_username = "Password";
$ftp_userpass = "UserName";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login with username and password
ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

//change dir
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images");
```

So I deleted this and just ran the rest, and it worked perfect.

I also changed my deleting function from

> php_delete

to

> php_unlink

like @Bob0t suggested so the final solution was to place this php file;

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
   echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
   unlink($filename);
}
```

in the directory where i wanted all file with extension ".jpg" deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

You are changing directory to the images directory, then from images directory you are deleteing "webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images/metal_textures_silver.jpg"

So I could be wrong, but it appears that you are trying to delete:

"webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images/webroot/CundyTech/BassClef/gallery-images/images/metal_textures_silver.jpg"

I think you just need:

```
ftp_delete($conn_id, "metal_textures_silver.jpg");
```

Comment: This seems like a logical anwer, in will test in the morning. How ever im not sure it even gets thay far as when the script it run on my remote server where the actaul files are it always throws the cant connect error?

Comment: if it's your server why you don't use `unlink()` ?

Comment: Didnt know about unlink? Will research now.

Comment: @DanCundy see [unlink() php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: @Bob9t it seems this unlink has the actually fuction i was building up to, being able to delete multiple files. I thank you for you comment and will follow this lead. If you suggest it as a differnt solution in an answer i will select it as the answer.